# interchanging limits in something like a Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I got this problem thats been bothering me. How can I interchange those limits D:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^{2}+k^{2}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}[ \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{k}{n})^{2}}]$. Now I know that theres something wrong cause I need to interchange the limits but even if I could I'd get something with not so much sense cause, what do I do with that $m$, I was thinking in creating a sequence but I couldnt see it.

So, any help would be really appreciated! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is decreasing, and $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ is finite. For $n=1,2,\dots,$ set

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{n}.$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n = \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx.$$

This follows from the observation that

$$\int_{0}^\infty f(x)\,dx - \frac{f(0)}{n}\le \int_{1/n}^\infty f(x)\,dx \le S_n \le \int_{0}^\infty f(x)\,dx,$$

which you can see from looking at the areas of rectangles in the usual way.

In our problem, $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2},$ and the desired limit is $\pi/2.$

Answer (score 4):

**Formally**, switching limits we get

$$\begin{align}\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{mn}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2} &= \lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{mn}\frac{1}{1+(k/n)^2}\\ &= \lim_{m \to \infty}\int_0^m \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} \\ &= \lim_{m \to \infty} \arctan(m)\\ &= \frac{\pi}{2}\end{align}$$

This is not easy to justify.  The usual theorems fail since the summand is not monotone and the series is not uniformly convergent. (Otherwise the limit would be $0$).

A rigorous proof would use
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^2+k^2} = \frac i2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{in-k}+\frac1{in+k}\right)
=-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{\pi i}{2}\cot(\pi in)\\
=-\frac1{2n}+\frac\pi2\coth(\pi n)$$

which implies

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}= \frac{\pi}{2}$$

since $\coth(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: In first place, thanks so much for your answer. Now, I do not see how you could interchange the limits in first place :(, could you please try to how did you get there D:. PD: I did understand the second part, the rigorous proof haha, but Im pretty sure this problem isnt meant to be solved like that

Comment: @user1trill:  As I said the limit is calculated rigorously by means of the series expansion for $\cot$. It happens that the manipulation into a Riemann sum with an appropriately chosen upper limit works as well.  If you are expecting an easy way to justify like uniform, monotone or dominated convergence then it won’t happen. Perhaps there is another way but it’s not coming to me at the moment.

Comment: "This is not easy to justify." It's actually easy in this case. See my post.

Comment: @zhw: My point is the limit cannot be obtained by a straightforward exchange of limits. Let $S_{mn} = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{n}{n^2 + k^2}$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2 + k^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} S_{mn} $. However, $\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{mn} = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_{nn} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{4}$.